# NodeJS: is it possible to host a nodeJS socket IO app with no express over it, just plain socket IO

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have a simple websocket app, no express just plain socket.IO

```
var port = process.env.port || 3000;

const app = require('http').createServer() , io = require('socket.io')(app);



app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('listening on' + port);
});


new Server();

function Server() {



    io.on('connection',function(socket){

        console.log("someone connected");


        socket.on('disconnect', () => {

            console.log("user got disconnected");



        });

    });



}
```

and i have been having issues hosting it because anytime i run it via forever.js i cant get to make it work outside localhost (outside the server(vm) with the servers external IP address). So I want to clarify if it is because i didn't install express or because socketio/nodejs cannot stand alone asa singular web socket server.

Comment: Sounds to me like a firewall that's blocking incoming traffic. It's not because of not using Express. FWIW, you don't even have to use `http`: `const io = require('socket.io').listen(port)` would also work.

Comment: @robertklep are you certain, because i tried hosting it on azure and heroku and i am getting the same issue. Or can you suggest any host to me which i can try it on ?

Comment: quite certain. I just tried and I can access a server that gets created using `require('socket.io').listen(...)` just fine through its external IP-address.

Comment: how did you call the socket on the server, like this "ws://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket", i want to know what i am doing wrong, and which server did you use ?

Comment: I used `require('socket.io-client')('http://EXT.ERN.AL.IP:3000/')`. Just to make sure: for `socket.io`, you need to use a `socket.io` client, not `WebSocket()`

Comment: how to i then call it from a websocket testing tool

Comment: There's [`sio`](https://github.com/connor4312/sio) that you could probably use.

Comment: so i should remove const socketIO = require('socket.io'); and add this require('socket.io-client')('http://EXT.ERN.AL.IP:3000/').

Comment: No, `socket.io-client` is how I tested that I could connect to the `socket.io` server through its external IP-address. Instead of using `socket.io-client`, you would use `sio` to try and connect to your `socket.io` server.

Comment: @robertklep so you think my code is fine ?

Comment: @robertklep please what server did you use to host your app

Comment: I just ran it on my Mac and accessed it from my Linux server.

Comment: @robertklep thanks, i got it work now